# Write a uint16 image

Tags: image, matlab, jpeg

How can I write an image of datatype `uint16` to a file in MATLAB? I try to write to the file using the following command, but it gives me an error

```
imwrite(pimg, 'h44', 'jpg')
```

> Error using writejpg>set_jpeg_props (line 183)
>   UINT16 image data requires bitdepth specifically set to
>   either 12 or 16.
>   Error in writejpg (line 49)
>   props = set_jpeg_props(data,varargin{:});
>   Error in imwrite (line 472)
>           feval(fmt_s.write, data, map, filename,
>           paramPairs{:});
>   Error in image16bit (line 666)
>   imwrite(imgnew1,'h44','jpg' );

Comment: you must set the `BitDepth` option in `imwrite`.

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the `BitDepth` option when saving JPEG images with more than 8-bits:

```
% note that 16-bit only accepts grayscale images
img = imread('peppers.png');
imwrite(im2uint16(img), '12bit.jpg', 'BitDepth',12);
imwrite(rgb2gray(im2uint16(img)), '16bit.jpg', 'BitDepth',16);
```

Unfortunately, not many programs have support for 12-bit/16-bit JPEG images, so you might not be able to open it externally. You could use the JPEG2000 format instead:

```
imwrite(im2uint16(img), 'out.jp2');
```