# How to write .dcm file as .jpg

Tags: matlab, image-processing, medical

I need to write .dcm file as .jpg, I tried the follwing code

```
Y = dicomread('IM-0001-0010.dcm');
imshow(Y,[]);
imwrite(Y,'save_loosless.jpg','Quality',100,'Mode','lossless','BitDepth',12);
imwrite(Y,'save_lossy.jp2','Quality',100,'Mode','lossy','BitDepth',12);
```

But it's giving the following error, I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681621/write-a-uint16-image) too. But again getting error. Please help me to solve.

> ??? Error using ==> writejp2k>process_argument_value at 137
>   'QualityLayers' must be an integer between 1 and 20.
>
> Error in ==> writejp2k>set_jp2c_props at 75
>       props = process_argument_value ( props, param, varargin{k+1} );
>
> Error in ==> writejp2k at 24 props =
>   set_jp2c_props(data,fmt,varargin{:});
>
> Error in ==> writejp2 at 31 writejp2k(data, map, filename, 'jp2',
>   varargin{:});
>
> Error in ==> imwrite at 477
>           feval(fmt_s.write, data, map, filename, paramPairs{:});
>
> Error in ==> Untitled at 4
>   imwrite(Y,'save_lossy.jp2','Quality',100,'Mode','lossy','BitDepth',12);

My MATLAB version is **R2011a**.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `'Quality'` is only possible for jpeg images. When saving to jp2, you need to remove this option.
You will also need to remove the `'BitDepth'` setting:
`imwrite(Y,'save_lossy.jp2','Mode','lossy');`

Comment: Okey. Thank you so much,it's working fine.How can I do this  for .jpeg images?

Comment: I cannot view the .jpeg image,Please help me to write .dcm file as .jpeg image

Comment: Your first command `imwrite(Y,'save_loosless.jpg','Quality',100,'Mode','lossless','BitDepth',12);` should be writing your dicom image as a jpeg in save_loosless.jpg.

Comment: It's writing.But I cannot view the image.

Comment: `yjpeg=imread('save_loosless.jpg'); imshow(yjpeg);` should work.

Comment: No.Plane back image is displayed

Comment: It's displaying plane black image

Comment: Then your dicom image is either plain black or it needs processing before being saved in jpeg format.

Comment: In the above code,imshow(Y,[]); when this line executed,I can see the image.when It's saved to .jpeg format.I cannot view the image